# Installing instance of Sql - SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am *extremely* new to SQL server. I am running the SQL Server 2008 R2 setup wizard and following a tutorial that I found online. Nowhere am I able to configure my instance, even after completing installing and going back to 'New Sql Server or Add Services...'

Having installed this, am I correct to assume that a default instance has been created for me? How do I found out what this is called, so that I can connect to it. Also, how am I able to configure this instance?

I'm sure this is something very obvious, but everything I've found online seems to be something like 'oh just go to the configure instance tab..etc', but I seriously don't see that in the setup that's running and I don't think I'd be able to configure this via the console.

Comment: Do you know what edition of SQL Server you installed?  Express, Standard, Eterprise?

Comment: developer edition

Answer (score 0):

During setup, you should have seen this screen:

[image: SQL Instance Configuration]

Assuming you left everything with their default settings, you'll have a default instance known as MSSQLSERVER. One way of checking the instance name is by looking in your services console (`services.msc`). There will be a service called '`SQL Server (<INSTANCENAME>)`'

If your instance has been installed as the default, you can connect to it via SQL Server Management Studio running on the machine itself by using '`.`' (a period, by itself), `localhost` or your machine name as the server name.

If it's a named instance, you can connect to it by using `.\INSTANCENAME`, `localhost\INSTANCENAME` or `HostName\INSTANCENAME`.